# How to configure Geowebcache as standalone application?

Tags: geoserver, geowebcache

I have a cluster of Geoserver and I am trying to use Geowebcache as a standalone application.

I downloaded the war file from this website:
https://sourceforge.net/projects/geowebcache/files/geowebcache/1.12.2/

I unzipped it inside a separate tomcat, restarted tomcat, modified the geowebcache.xml so it links to Geoserver layers and it worked fine (I can see my layers in Geowebcache demo page).

Now, how can I use this layers directly from Geoserver? For example, when a client makes a request, Geoserver will verify if the layer exists in the cache before creating it.

Comment: your client should only talk to GWC not GeoServer

Comment: I can see the layer from this link http://ip-address:port/geowebcache/demo/raster%20test%20layer?gridSet=EPSG:4326&format=image/png, the client should access the layer from the same link?